# HTML - Javascript on check

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, material-design, selection

Okay first of all i have code like this

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test1">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test2">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test3">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test4">
```

Now i modified it like this

```
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test1" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test2" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test3" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test4" onclick="myFunction()">
```

And this is myfunction

```
function myFunction() {
  var testArr = ["test1", "test2"];
  for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(testArr[i].value);
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
    Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000)
  } 
}
}
```

What i am trying to do ?

I am trying to show a notice/Dialog that materialize.toast will show when checkbox with id test1 or test2 are checked. and doesn't do anything when test3 or test4 is selected. i hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById(testArr[i]);` without `.value`

Comment: `var checkBox = document.getElementById(testArr[i]).value;`

Comment: @JasonB that worked a bit but after i checked test1, it showed message but on the same time when i checked test3 with test1 checked it again showed me message whereas it should not show message when test3 is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the below is what you are looking for.

First, add `this` as a parameter in the `function` used in the `checkbox`, that way you can trigger the clicked `checkbox`

And then in the function check if the clicked `checkbox` is checked, and have the special id, then do whatever you want

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var testArr = ["test1", "test2"];
  
  var chkId = $(e).attr("id");
  if (e.checked == true && testArr.indexOf(chkId) !== -1) {
    console.log("Materialize goes here!"); //Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000)
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test2" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test3" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="test4" onclick="myFunction(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code it will helps you.

```
function myFunction(id) {
var c = document.getElementById(id);
if((id=='test1' || id=='test2') && c.checked)
{
 Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with this line 
`var checkBox = document.getElementById(testArr[i].value);`

It has to be

```
var checkBox = document.getElementById(testArr[i]).value;
```

Also to know if checkbox is checked, there is no need to get it's value

```
document.getElementById(testArr[i]).checked
```

will return state of checkbox

Comment: not woking!  this worked (but still has few issues) > document.getElementById(testArr[i]);

Comment: this is working > https://jsfiddle.net/e8beua1f/ but when you check test2 (it shows notice) but when you check test3 its again showing notice keeping 2 checked. where as it should not show alert when 3 is checked even if 2nd is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkBox = document.getElementById(testArr[i]);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: that worked a bit but after i checked test1, it showed message but on the same time when i checked test3 with test1 checked it again showed me message whereas it should not show message when test3 is checked

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    debugger;
  var testArr = ["test1", "test2"];
  for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(testArr[i]);
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
    alert('I am a toast!');
  } 
}
}
```

removing value from `document.getElementById(testArr[i]).value` works for me

or you can directly check checkbox is checked or not using following function

```
function myFunction() {
    debugger;
  var testArr = ["test1", "test2"];
  for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    var flag = document.getElementById(testArr[i]).checked;
    if (flag){
    alert('I am a toast!');
  } 
}
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e8beua1f/ i checked box test1, test2 and test3 but it again still showing for test3 which it should not